# Spring JPA - when to use relational mapping? eg @OneToMany

Tags: orm, spring-data-jpa

I know and understand this concept, already applied on my coding. however, what i dont understand is when should we use? should we implement this everytime we have relational database? or when situation requires us?

eg 1:

```
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("John");

    PhoneNumber ph1 = new PhoneNumber();
    ph1.setNumber("1234567890");
    ph1.setType("cell");

    PhoneNumber ph2 = new PhoneNumber();
    ph2.setNumber("0987654321");
    ph2.setType("home");

    customer.addPhoneNumber(ph1);
    customer.addPhoneNumber(ph2);

    repository.save(customer);
```

above is where a customer has many numbers and for this use-case, a NEW customer AND multiple NEW numbers are created, and saved (in db) which is why we need mapping. fully understood.

but there's another example - eg 2:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5E0O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shkg2.png)

there's 2 tables in db - seller (PK: seller_id) and products (PK: prod_id, FK: seller_id ). so to add product, u must include seller_id as one of the fields. This is relational too. but in contrast to 1st eg, i dont need to create NEW seller and multiple NEW products. i need to create new seller FIRST, then after that, add products many times over, any time. for this case, do i need to do the mapping too?

edit: my q is, can i just use native query to get the list of products from 1 seller?  if yes, then whats the point of mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a @OneToMany relationship between them because one seller is selling more than one product. Here this can be unidirectional or bidirectional depending upon the scenario. When you do unidirectional mapping between them then by the seller you can access all products he/she sells. And when you do bidirectional you can you can access all products he/she sells and by-product detail you can access by which seller sells it.

Comment: i can use native query to achieve this... so why do i still need to map?